How can I shuffle time blocks in time series without overlap in R?
Let's assume there is a group of 3 persons, for which I have a time series of when they start and finish an activity.
An example dataframe would be:
library(tidyverse)
GrXX <- tibble(Individual = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = c(2, 3, 5)),
               Frame_beginning = c(1, 16, 7, 21, 29, 3, 9, 12, 19, 27),
               Frame_end = c(3, 22, 15, 24, 30, 7, 10, 12, 24, 30),
               Duration = Frame_end - Frame_beginning + 1,
               Frame_end_valid_group = 30)

This group can be represented by the following figure:
I would love to shuffle this group around, so that the time blocks within individuals are randomly placed, without overlap within individuals (there can be overlap between individuals). Additonally, all original time blocks should also be fully on the shuffled timeline (i.e., they should not start or finish outside of the original timeline). One potential shuffling could be the following: 
My question is how to do that in R, in an efficient way. I started some code, but it seems very complex for the task, and does not prevent all overlaps. Here it is:
GrXX_shuffled <- tibble()

for (i in c("A", "B", "C")) {
  temp <- GrXX %>%
    filter(Individual == i) %>%
    arrange(-Duration, Frame_beginning)
  
  valid_frames <- c()
  Frame_shuffled_start <- c()
  Frame_shuffled_end <- c()
  Frame_earliest <- 1
  
  for (j in 1:nrow(temp)) {
    temp2 <- temp[j, ]
    
    if(j == 1) {
    valid_frames <- 1:(temp2$Frame_end_valid_group - temp2$Duration + 1)
    
    temp2 <- temp2 %>%
      mutate(Frame_beginning_shuffled = sample(valid_frames, size = 1), .after = Frame_beginning) %>%
      mutate(Frame_end_shuffled = Frame_beginning_shuffled + Duration - 1, .after = Frame_end)
    
    GrXX_shuffled <- bind_rows(GrXX_shuffled, temp2)
    }

    if(j != 1) {
      valid_frames <- c(Frame_earliest:(Frame_shuffled_start[j-1] - temp2$Duration - 1),
                        (Frame_shuffled_end[j-1] + 2):(temp2$Frame_end_valid_group - temp2$Duration + 1))
      
      valid_frames <- valid_frames[valid_frames >= 1 & valid_frames <= 30]
      
      temp2 <- temp2 %>%
        mutate(Frame_beginning_shuffled = sample(valid_frames, size = 1), .after = Frame_beginning) %>%
        mutate(Frame_end_shuffled = Frame_beginning_shuffled + Duration - 1, .after = Frame_end)
      
      GrXX_shuffled <- bind_rows(GrXX_shuffled, temp2)
    }
    
    Frame_shuffled_start <- sort(c(Frame_shuffled_start, temp2$Frame_beginning_shuffled))
    Frame_shuffled_end <- sort(c(Frame_shuffled_end, temp2$Frame_end_shuffled))
    Frame_earliest <- min(valid_frames_2)
  }
}

The idea behind the code is to:

for each individual select the block with the longest duration and shuffle it around on the empty timeline (and it should not start too late so that the full block is still fully on the timeline)
then go for the next longest block (if it exists) and place it in the rest of the timeline, without overlap with any previous already-shuffled blocks
repeat until no more blocks have to be shuffled

Any idea how to solve this efficiently?
Many thanks in advance :-)

Curious as well as how you did your plotting, while not to your question as answer below, also useful to add so others can reproduce your results.

@Chris Well, the plotting was done manually in PowerPoint...

It;s a pity, ...

Here's an efficient function to do what was described. It assumes discrete timesteps as in the OP's example.
library(data.table)
library(RcppAlgos) # for `compositionsSample`
library(Rfast) # for `colShuffle` and `colCumSums`

shuffle <- function(dt, n = 1L) {
  f <- function(v, m) {
    k <- length(v)
    k1 <- k + 1L
    as.data.table(
      cbind(
        rep = rep(1:n, each = k),
        matrix(
          colCumSums(
            `dim<-`(
              rbind(
                `dim<-`(t(compositionsSample(0:(m - sum(v)), k + 1, TRUE,
                                             n = n)[,-k - 1]), NULL),
                `dim<-`(colShuffle(matrix(v, k, n)), NULL)
              ), c(2*k, n)
            )
          ) + 1:0,
          n*k, 2, TRUE, list(NULL, c("Frame_beginning", "Frame_end"))
        )
      )
    )[,`:=`(Duration = Frame_end - Frame_beginning + 1,
            Frame_end_valid_group = m)]
  }
  setorder(
    setcolorder(dt[,f(Duration, Frame_end_valid_group[1]), Individual], "rep"),
    rep, Individual
  )
}

Demonstrating:
shuffle(setDT(GrXX))[]
#>       rep Individual Frame_beginning Frame_end Duration Frame_end_valid_group
#>     <num>     <char>           <num>     <num>    <num>                 <num>
#>  1:     1          A               3         9        7                    30
#>  2:     1          A              27        29        3                    30
#>  3:     1          B               2         3        2                    30
#>  4:     1          B               5         8        4                    30
#>  5:     1          B              21        29        9                    30
#>  6:     1          C               1         5        5                    30
#>  7:     1          C               8         8        1                    30
#>  8:     1          C              12        13        2                    30
#>  9:     1          C              17        22        6                    30
#> 10:     1          C              26        29        4                    30

It can also do multiple shuffles using the n argument:
shuffle(GrXX, 3)[]
#>       rep Individual Frame_beginning Frame_end Duration Frame_end_valid_group
#>     <num>     <char>           <num>     <num>    <num>                 <num>
#>  1:     1          A              17        23        7                    30
#>  2:     1          A              25        27        3                    30
#>  3:     1          B               5         8        4                    30
#>  4:     1          B              16        17        2                    30
#>  5:     1          B              19        27        9                    30
#>  6:     1          C               4         4        1                    30
#>  7:     1          C               6         9        4                    30
#>  8:     1          C              11        12        2                    30
#>  9:     1          C              15        20        6                    30
#> 10:     1          C              25        29        5                    30
#> 11:     2          A               8        10        3                    30
#> 12:     2          A              19        25        7                    30
#> 13:     2          B               5         6        2                    30
#> 14:     2          B               8        16        9                    30
#> 15:     2          B              20        23        4                    30
#> 16:     2          C               3         7        5                    30
#> 17:     2          C              11        12        2                    30
#> 18:     2          C              14        17        4                    30
#> 19:     2          C              19        19        1                    30
#> 20:     2          C              21        26        6                    30
#> 21:     3          A              12        14        3                    30
#> 22:     3          A              23        29        7                    30
#> 23:     3          B               4         5        2                    30
#> 24:     3          B              10        13        4                    30
#> 25:     3          B              15        23        9                    30
#> 26:     3          C               2         7        6                    30
#> 27:     3          C               9        10        2                    30
#> 28:     3          C              12        16        5                    30
#> 29:     3          C              19        19        1                    30
#> 30:     3          C              23        26        4                    30

And it's fast:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(shuffle(GrXX, 100))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#>  shuffle(GrXX, 100) 1.9616 2.1486 2.343154 2.22235 2.36755 5.8275   100


Thanks a lot @jblood94 ! It looks like it's working. It will definitely take me a while to understand how data.table is working... but it always look super efficient at many tasks ;-) It looks like it is also always able to sample all blocks of all durations (i.e. not being stuck by not having enough space to put a long block at the end of the procedure). Looking forward to trying it out on the real dataset :-) Thanks again!

I tried to modify your code to able to include a Group column in the final output, between columns "rep" and "Individual", but it did not work. I tried dt[,f(Duration, Frame_end_valid_group[1]), Group, Individual], but it seems like I can only include 1 column, either Group or Individual, not both. Let's say that in my example all individuals came from Group 1, how would you modify the code?

dt[,f(Duration, Frame_end_valid_group[1]), .(Group, Individual)]
